# How to switch camera in "com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView" library

Tags: android, camera, shared-libraries, android-camera

I tried very hard, But I am not able to switch the camera in `com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView` library. Please Tell me if anyone know to switch the camera in this library.

---

Version of `com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView` library is - `0.13.1`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Switch to the back camera.

```
cameraView.setFacing(CameraKit.Constants.FACING_BACK);
```

Switch to the front camera.

```
cameraView.setFacing(CameraKit.Constants.FACING_FRONT);
```